# MATLAB function speed

Tags: matlab, performance, function

I have been tasked to speed up a rather large MATLAB project (caveat: minimal MATLAB experience). I have been using the profiler and found that the majority of time spent was on a couple different functions passing large data sets.

Majority of time spent calling this function

```
[foo,bar,baz,qux,quux]=function1(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i);
```

calling this

```
function [foo,bar,baz,qux,quux]=function1(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i);
... % which calls this the following function
[foo2,bar2,baz2,qux2,quux2,sTrack]=function2(a2,b2,c2,d2,e2,f2,g2,h2,i2,j2,k2,l2,m2,n2);
...
```

the call to function2 is another taxing call which takes up the second most time in my timed runs

this pattern of functions calling subsequent functions appears to be the first place for me to focus on improving performance.

Current Ideas:

1. I was looking into not using global variables where possible.
2. The code seems to be vectorized so I dont believe I can save any time there.
3. Finding a way to speed up the passing of data to functions.
4. Saw a random comment somewhere that suggested I load specific functions when needed (kind of like importing a class in other languages) ... not sure if this is a thing.

Comment: We really can't comment unless we actually see your code.  Those ideas are meaningless without actually seeing what you're doing.  If you show us the critical parts of where it's slowing down, we can verify your claims.  BTW, don't use `inline` at all.  This is deprecated behaviour and you should use anonymous functions instead.  Under the hood `inline` uses `eval` and any conservative MATLAB programmer will tell you that `eval` is akin to shaking hands with the devil: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/7860-inline-vs-anonymous-functions

Comment: edit coming sir

Comment: With minimal matlab involvement (e.g. experience, interest), little success you will have in optimizing that involvement. Google is *crowded*, *overflowing* with examples (such [this](https://mathworks.com/videos/optimizing-and-accelerating-your-matlab-code-107711.html). But the profiler is a good starting point. So, put your hands to good use, and start working.

Comment: None of your listed ideas -though adviced for style and other goals- has anything to do with code optimization -perhaps only vectorizing and profiling-. Again Google, and Mathworks is filled with examples. So come back when you already have at least several of these guides read and applied.

Comment: Beside the aforementioned, if your team have a *real* interest on code optimization, you should start thinking in a code compiling strategy. Also, as @rayryeng said, without any detail or idea of the process bottlenecks, this question is completely useless to answer.

Comment: thanks for your time ... I am working hard on taking all the code in and will get right on more specific guides for optimization. Good looking out on the compiling strategy! I was hoping this was something that there was a good quick trick to solve that maybe I was just missing. Like most things in life ... just gotta grind a bit. Again thanks for your time

Comment: Comment out the code in function2, get it to return some dummy data for foo2,bar2,baz2,qux2,quux2,sTrack and then run the profiler. If it runs much quicker then it's not the interface but the calculations inside the function.